# How does the touch sensitivity toggle work?

Tags: 8.0, nokia-lumia-920

I have set the touch sensitivity in settings to "**high**". But, when I use gloves it always take some time for my Nokia Lumia 920 to adapt the touch sensitivity to allow glove touch input. The delay is ambiguous and can take between a one or two seconds up to ten seconds.

Does anybody know if there is some gesture or other way to immediately turn on high sensitivity without delay?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be effective to **"tap and hold"** with your glove for approximate *two* seconds and then start swiping and tappin'.

Answer (score 1):

Different materials transmit your body's conductivity differently. I've gotten better results with thick pair of cotton winter gloves than a thin pair of nonconductive synthetic ones

Try a different pair of gloves and see if your response is better.

Comment: I am sorry It didn't made any difference for me. I believe it is a using problem.